# Different style/color for some specific references using natbib

Tags: fonts, color, citing, natbib

I need to differentiate some specific references from the others, for both the text and the reference list at the end of the document. Let's say I want the "regular" ones in blue and the specific (i.e. mine actually) in orange. There is way with BibTeX see here: [Different style/color for some specific references using Bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224568/different-style-color-for-some-specific-references-using-bibtex)

But I'd like to do similar things with `natbib`.

(Following is similar to the previous post but it now concerns `natbib` instead of BibTeX)

I have something quite standard like this:

in the `.tex` file:

```
\usepackage[authoryear,colon,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\begin{document}

Something to say \citep{one_regular_ref01,another_regular_ref02,my_specific01}.
```

My `.bib` is normal as I parsed the entries from journal's website.

This gives me something like this:

> Something to say [RegRef et al, 2001; aRegRef et al, 2002; My_paper, 2010].

Everything has the same color. But I'd like my own ref in a different one.

Ok I can edit the `.bib` file but it seems odd to me as I can potentially use the same `.bib` for another document without this very specific need.

I was thinking that adding `*` (for instance) to the end of the citation call (i.e. `\citep{my_specific01*}`) could be a way to discriminate the specific citations but now how can I tell `natbib` to change the way these references are displayed (again in the text and the reference list) to a different color or potentially any font style.

I did not find anything on the web that treat and solve this very specific task using `natbib` but any ideas would be more than appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to have two separate bibliographies instead of color-coding them?

Comment: I'm not sure to follow you. you mean two .bib files ? If so why not, but how in such case, differentiate them while citing?

Comment: Have a look at the multibib package or the following: http://texblog.org/2012/10/22/multiple-bibliographies-with-biblatex/

Comment: I'm afraid the dichotomy you're setting up, with `natbib` on one side and BibTeX on the other, is quite misleading. Are you maybe thinking of the difference between `natbib`'s citation commands versus the "basic LaTeX" `\cite` macro?

Comment: I have totally reworked my answer.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED to totally replace my earlier attempt, which did not meet the OP's specifications.
EDITED to provide 2nd TRIAL VERSION.

SAFE VERSION:

With the 1st (safer) version, I was unable to make the year in the cite colored, because apparently it uses a sorting pattern on that field (the `#3` argument to `\harvarditem`), and therefore must remain alphabetic.  I accomplished what I did by redefining `\harvarditem` to call on `\[ref]color` where `[ref]` is the cite key.  These colors are defined by `\refcolor{A01}{green}` which, for example, defines a macro `\A01color` as `{green}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,ifthen,filecontents}
\usepackage[authoryear,colon,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{dcu}
\def\refcolor#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname#1color\endcsname{#2}}

\refcolor{A01}{green}
\refcolor{A01b}{cyan}
\refcolor{C03}{red}

\def\setbibcolor#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname#1color\endcsname\relax%
    \color{black}%
  \else%
    \color{\csname#1color\endcsname}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\harvarditem[4][]{%
 \if\relax#1\relax
   \setbibcolor{#4}\bibitem[\setbibcolor{#4}#2(#3)]{#4}%
 \else
   \bibitem[#1(#3)#2]{#4}%
 \fi
}%
\makeatother
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha}
}
@misc{A01b,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha TWO}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo}
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie}
}
@misc{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Delta}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
cite \cite{A01, A01b, B02, C03, D04}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

TRIAL UPDATE:

By redefining

```
\renewcommand\harvarditem[4][]{%
 \if\relax#1\relax
   \setbibcolor{#4}\bibitem[\setbibcolor{#4}#2\ {[}#3{]}()]{#4}%
 \else
   \bibitem[#1(#3)#2]{#4}%
 \fi
}%
```

as such, I get the desired result for this MWE.  However, I am not sure what I may have broken in the process... year-based sorting, I presume. Clearly I fixed the year delimiters as `[]` but there may be other things, too.  But here it is, if it suits.

[image]