# How to colorise specific entries in the bibliography and corresponding references in the text with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, color, citing

This question is a follow-up to previous questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368247/how-to-colorise-specific-entries-in-the-bibliography-and-corresponding-reference) (with `biblatex`) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224568/different-style-color-for-some-specific-references-using-bibtex).

I'm using `biblatex` with `alphabetic` style and achieve coloring the whole reference in the bibliography (numeric style is used in the first above link). I can color the citation key in the text using some options of the `hyperref` package.

What I want to get is a colored citation key in the text and the same one in the bibliography, without coloring the entire reference, as shown in the above second link.

Is there a way to adapt the first question above to the `alphabetic` style? I tried but am rather new to `biblatex`.

Here is my MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\PassOptionsToPackage{
            natbib=true,
            backend=bibtex,      
            style=alphabetic,
            doi=false,
            maxcitenames=1, % 1 auteur max dans la citation dans le texte
            maxbibnames=1 % 1 auteur max dan la biblio
        }{biblatex}         
        \usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo}
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie}
}
@misc{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Delta}
}
\end{filecontents}    

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\addtocategory{important}{A01}
\addtocategory{important}{B02}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelprefix}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
    {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\color{orange}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{A01}
  \cite{B02}
  \cite{C03}       
  \cite{D04}      

  \cite{A01,B02,C03,D04}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just remove the `\AtEveryBibitem` block and change all occurences of `labelnumber` to `labelalpha` (since you are not using a `numeric` but an `alphabetic` style). You will also want to colour `extraalpha`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic,
  maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=1,
  doi=false,
  natbib=true,]{biblatex}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\addtocategory{important}{A01}
\addtocategory{important}{B02}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelprefix}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
    {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo}
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie}
}
@misc{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Delta}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{A01}
  \cite{B02}
  \cite{C03}
  \cite{D04}

  \cite{A01,B02,C03,D04}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Coloured citations and bibliography labels.]

You should seriously consider switching to `backend=biber,` from `backend=bibtex,`. You can only use all of `biblatex`'s features with the Biebr backend. Switching is usually as easy as replacing `backend=bibtex,` with `backend=biber,` and running Biber instead of BibTeX ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) helps you with your editor configuration).

---

It may be slightly easier to just modify the `cite` bibmacro directly instead of changing several different field formats.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic,
  maxcitenames=1, maxbibnames=1,
  doi=false,
  natbib=true,]{biblatex}


\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{important}
\addtocategory{important}{A01}
\addtocategory{important}{B02}

\DeclareFieldFormat{colourimportant}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{#1}}
    {#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printtext[colourimportant]{%
      \printfield{labelprefix}%
      \printfield{labelalpha}%
      \printfield{extraalpha}%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
        {}}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{%
  \ifcategory{important}
    {\textcolor{orange}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
    {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha}
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo}
}
@misc{C03,
  author = {Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2003},
  title = {Charlie}
}
@misc{D04,
  author = {Duthor, D.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Delta}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{A01}
  \cite{B02}
  \cite{C03}
  \cite{D04}

  \cite{A01,B02,C03,D04}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is it! That's perfect, it works like a charm. Thank you :)

Comment: I've another question related to the previous answer.

If, in the .bib file, two entries are from the same author and  publishedthe same year, citations in the text will appear in the above defined color + a letter, to distinguish them properly, which isn't colored.

Is there a way to impose the same color code on that added letter?

Thank you!

Comment: @Aurélien See the edit, please.

Comment: I would like to rather test if there is an annotation on one of the authors instead of adding a category (ex. `author+an={2=highlight}`). I tried `\iffieldannotation` `\ifitemannotation` and others without success. Any suggestion?

Comment: Follow-up question is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/638246/35864